# Angular 2 security: redirect to clicked route after login?

Tags: authentication, angular, angular2-routing

I'm building my first app using the release version of Angular 2 (I'm on 2.1.0 currently).  I have set up a [Route Guard](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards), and I am using it in my routing.ts to secure one of the routes with authentication.  When clicked, if not logged in, it redirects the user to the login route.  There they can login, and if authenticated, it sets a localStorage token.  Here's where I have a problem.  I want to then redirect the user to the route they clicked on initially before they were redirected to the login, but I can't figure out how to get the clicked route once they hit the Guard canActivate method, or on the login.  This seems like a fairly common usage scenario, but I can't find any examples of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this is my stripped out example which should illustrate the point:

```
    @Injectable()
    export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate
    {
        toUrl;

        constructor(public authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
                    public router: Router)
        {
        }

        canActivate(route, state): boolean
        {
            this.toUrl = state.url; //This is the url where its going

            if (this.authenticationService.isLoggedIn()) return true;

            this.router.navigate(['/login', {redirect: this.toUrl}]);        

        }

}
```

and in the login component use the ngOnInit to check for any redirect ulrs:

```
export class LoginComponent
{
    redirect;

    constructor(
                private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
                private route: ActivatedRoute,
                private router: Router)
    {
    }

    ngOnInit()
    {
        this.redirect = this.route.snapshot.params['redirect'];
    }

    logIn(): void
    {
        this.authenticationService
            .login(this.searchParams)
            .subscribe(
                () =>
                {
                    this.logInSuccess();
                },
                error =>
                {
                    this.logInFail(error)
                })
    }

    logInSuccess(): void
    {

        if (this.redirect)
        {
            this.router.navigateByUrl(this.redirect);
        }
        else
        {
            this.router.navigate([''])
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: So the way the route guard works is, it hits the canActivate method of the guard to determine if the user is already authenticated.  In that method, I have tried grabbing the this.router.url, but it's equal to the route the user was on when they clicked the secured route link, not that new route.  The URL in the address bar is the current route, not the new secured route.  So I have no way of knowing which secured route the user clicked.  Or at least I don't think I do, I'm hoping someone can tell me how to get that new route so I can do exactly what you suggested.

Comment: Ill implement this in my app have been meaning to do this for a while. I share how I done it.

Comment: I see what you mean, I have been digging around trying to get the new route where it is going. Can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: I did find that if I pass in the ActivatedRouteSnapshot, I can get the route that the user is going to through this value:

    constructor(private snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
        let newRoute = this.snapshot._futureSnapshot._routerState.url
    }
 
But those properties aren't exposed, and generate errors in the code in VS Code.  There should be a better way to access that value, but so far I can't find it...

Comment: Turns out that the `canActivate(route, state)` has a param which tells you next url.

Comment: @runyards Which param are you referring to. I can't find any third parameter for canDeactivate in Angular4.